# Artifact has not been packaged yet

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am letting Maven copy some dependency files into a specific location for a GWT project. The `maven-dependency-plugin` does the job and so far it works. The only Problem is that I'm getting an error from Eclipse that says:

> `Artifact has not been packaged yet. When used on reactor artifact, copy should be executed after packaging: see MDEP-187.`

I have tried to change the `<phase>` but that did not work. How can I get rid of that error and why is it there because Maven builds as intended.

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/war/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-187 still seems active. Maybe you can ask for a workaround there?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Created 12/Nov/08; Priority: Major ... well that's sad.. but thanks for the hint!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Artifact has not been packaged yet - maven-dependency-plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101135/artifact-has-not-been-packaged-yet-maven-dependency-plugin)

Comment: worked for me , but wondering is it the best solution

Comment: I know this problem has been years. but I recently had this issues as well, and it is not specific for eclipse. Eventually, changing the `phase` from `generate-resources` to `prepare-package` solved it (I know your case id different but it worth to try different phases to see if it will unblock you).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I got the same error and I solved this issue with a workaround. I have compiled and installed the project with Maven in a console outside Eclipse IDE. After I have refreshed the project inside Eclipse IDE and error has disappeared.

Comment: This question is kind of old so I cannot try this out anymore. Since you have some up-votes I assume your solution works which is why I am going to accept this answer.

Comment: The problem seems to be still alive with "Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT APT" 1.5.3 and/or maven-resources-plugin 3.1.0. a "Run As Maven clean" seems to be a workaround for me.

Comment: This issues is related with IDE.  as my case, i use IntelliJ IDEA. i resolve this issues by unchecked Resolve Workspace artifacts button

Answer (score 15):

There is a solution similar to [s1moner3d answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45998827/452775) which doesn't require changes to `pom.xml` file.

Go to *Window > Preferences > Maven > Lifecycle Mappings* and click on the *Open workspace lifecycle mappings metadata* button.
[image: screenshot]

Than add `pluginExecution` entry like in the code below. If the file is empty, copy the entire content below. You might need to change `versionRange`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lifecycleMappingMetadata>
  <pluginExecutions>
    <pluginExecution>
      <pluginExecutionFilter>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <versionRange>2.10</versionRange>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
      </pluginExecutionFilter>
      <action>
        <ignore />
      </action>
    </pluginExecution>
  </pluginExecutions>
</lifecycleMappingMetadata>
```

In order for this to take effect go back to *Preferences* and click *Reload workspace lifecycle mappings metadata*. Update Maven projects and / or rebuild. The error should be gone.

Useful if you cannot or don't want to modify `pom.xml` for any reasons but want to stop your Eclipse m2e from executing particular goal of a particular plugin.

Comment: It works for me. But there is a missing tag in the given XML. You can add `<pluginExecutions>` after `<lifecycleMappingMetadata>`

Answer (score 12):

I solved by setting the plugin phase to **prepare-package**. I know it's still a workaround, but I think it's cleaner than compile externally.

```
<plugins>
        [...]
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        [YOUR_CONFIGURATION]
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        [...]
    </plugins>
```

**EDIT:**

This is not fully solving: sometimes it works, other times not.

The final solution is to use the **Lifecycle Mapping Maven Dummy Plugin** through an *eclipse-only* maven profile:

```
 <profile>
     <id>only-eclipse</id>
     <activation>
        <property>
         <name>m2e.version</name>
        </property>
     </activation>
     <build>
      <pluginManagement>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                               <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                               <versionRange>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</versionRange>
                               <goals>
                                   <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                               </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                              <ignore />
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
       </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
     </build>
 </profile>
```

Comment: The same pluginExecution can be put into workspace lifecycle mappings metadata, solves the issue without touching pom.xml

Comment: @ixi cool! please explain better. Where exactly? In which file?

Comment: sure will submit the answer today later

Answer (score 12):

I had to wrap plugins tag under pluginManagement to make the error go away.

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>../../lib/</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Comment: I thinked it worked, but it just prevents the inclusion of this plugin :-/

Comment: The copy-dependencies never executes when wrapped in <pluginManagement>. It gets rid of the error but  have to remove to get the dependencies to copy using the mvn CLI.

Comment: This does work but what he is missing is that you have to re-add the plugin outside of <pluginManagement> so add      

<plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>

after </pluginManagement> and before </build>

Answer (score 8):

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46972805/16452042) to fix the problem. That 2017 update to m2eclipse means you don't need to use the `pluginManagment` xml as in s1moner3d's answer, and so that gets rid of the "POM not found" warning I got for the 'lifecycle-mapping' `artifactId` tag when I included it.

To summarize:

1. You don't need a `pluginManagment` block for org.eclipse.m2e
2. Add a `<?m2e ignore?>` tag in your `<execution>` tag(s) :

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.0</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <?m2e ignore?>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                   ...{your configuration} ... 
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>               
   </plugin>
   ```

https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/release-notes-17.html#new-syntax-for-specifying-lifecycle-mapping-metadata

Comment: Worked for me (unlike others).

Comment: worked for me with a little twist : 
- the **<?m2e ignore?>** might ignore the configuration when doing Eclipse->Maven-> update project.

=> If you want this to be triggered when the eclipse .project / .classpath is recreated, the **<?m2eexecute onConfiguration?>** can be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

For those returning to this question, it may be useful to report seeing the same problem in Eclipse against `maven-dependency-plugin` version 2.8.  This was in the `package` phase:

`Artifact has not been packaged yet. When used on reactor artifact, copy should be executed after packaging: see MDEP-187. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy:copy-proguard:package)`

In this case upgrading to 3.1.1 solved the problem:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-proguard</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            ...
```

Comment: I came here looking for a solution to the same problem.  My plugin was already set to 3.1.1; wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This issue related to eclipse IDE: 
Solution is to update **M2E Connector for the maven-dependency-plugin** 
Steps :
Help ---> Eclipse Marketplace.. then update the plugin.