# Artifact has not been packaged yet MDEP-98

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

When compiling one of the Patient Matching algorithm files -> Choicemaker 
i found this error

I have tried few solutions from 
[Artifact has not been packaged yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642630/artifact-has-not-been-packaged-yet)
i still haven't found the solution 
Kindly please Help

THE ERROR IS AS FOLLOWS

> Artifact has not been packaged yet. When used on reactor artifact,
>   unpack should be executed after packaging: see MDEP-98.
>   (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:unpack-dependencies:
>   e2-standard-platform:pre-integration-  ....

The ERROR IS SHOWN NEXT TO   tag

This is the POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.choicemaker.cm</groupId>
    <artifactId>choicemaker-base</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../choicemaker-base/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.choicemaker.cmit</groupId>
  <artifactId>cm-analyzer-ce-it</artifactId>

  <name>Integration Test: ChoiceMaker Analyzer, Part 1</name>
  <description><![CDATA[
  Integration test for the standard-E2 version of CM Analyzer, Community Edition.
  ]]></description>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <eclipse.application.dir>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/eclipse.application.dir</eclipse.application.dir>
    <eclipse.application.examples.dir>${eclipse.application.dir}/examples</eclipse.application.examples.dir>
    <eclipse.application.plugins.dir>${eclipse.application.dir}/plugins</eclipse.application.plugins.dir>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          <compilerArgument>-g</compilerArgument>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>



          <execution>                         ---------> ERROR
            <id>plugins</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includeArtifactIds>cm-analyzer-ce</includeArtifactIds>
              <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
              <outputDirectory>${eclipse.application.dir}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>



          <execution>                         ---------> ERROR
            <id>e2-standard-platform</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>eclipse2prj</classifier>
              <includeArtifactIds>com.choicemaker.e2.std,com.choicemaker.cm.modelmaker.std</includeArtifactIds>
              <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
              <outputDirectory>${eclipse.application.plugins.dir}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>



          <execution>                          ---------->  ERROR
            <id>examples</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includeArtifactIds>simple_person_matching</includeArtifactIds>
              <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
              <outputDirectory>${eclipse.application.examples.dir}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>



        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.choicemaker.e2</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.choicemaker.e2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.choicemaker.e2it</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.choicemaker.e2it</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.choicemaker.e2</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.choicemaker.e2.std</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.choicemaker.e2</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.choicemaker.e2.std</artifactId>
      <classifier>eclipse2prj</classifier>
      <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.choicemaker.cm</groupId>
      <artifactId>cm-analyzer-ce</artifactId>
      <classifier>distrib</classifier>
      <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.choicemaker.cm</groupId>
      <artifactId>simple_person_matching</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.choicemaker.cm</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.choicemaker.cm.modelmaker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.choicemaker.cm</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.choicemaker.cm.modelmaker.std</artifactId>
      <classifier>eclipse2prj</classifier>
      <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.choicemaker.cm</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.boot</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.choicemaker.cm</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.launcher</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: This error message implies that your inter module dependencies are simply wrong..furthermore the given relativePath is a build smell cause this shows that the logical structure of your project is not represented by the directory structure...

Comment: I had a conversation with the developers of the software, they say the code is like 6years old. They have a better code now which they obviously declined to share

Comment: About which developers are you talking about?

Comment: Choicemaker is an algorithm for matching/deduplication of records of a database. It is typically used in the medical industry for duplicate medical records. Choicemaker is one such software for it. So I had spoken to choice-maker devs about the working of this code. They mentioned the above code was obselete